Shopware 6: Updating orders' sales channel when customer's sales channel changes
I'm working on a Shopware 6 plugin that allows changing a customer's sales channel in the admin panel. However, I've encountered an issue where after changing a customer's sales channel, they can no longer see their previous orders in their customer account in the frontend.
Here's what I've done so far:

I've overridden the sw-customer-base-info component to allow changing the customer's sales channel.
I'm successfully updating the customer's salesChannelId when it's changed in the admin.

Here's a snippet of my current code:
watch: {
    salesChannelId: {
        immediate: true,
        handler(newVal) {
            if (newVal) {
                this.customerRepository.get(newVal).then((salesChannel) => {
                     this.salesChannelUser = salesChannel;
                }).catch(error => {
                     console.error('Error fetching salesChannelUser:', error);
                });
            }
        }
    }
};

The problem is that existing orders are still associated with the old sales channel, causing them to disappear from the customer's view in the frontend.
What I need help with:
How can I fetch all orders associated with a customer when their sales channel is changed?
How can I update the salesChannelId of these orders to match the customer's new sales channel?
